# Monit 5.3.2 not working on Ubuntu 12.04 x86_64

Tags: linux, ubuntu, monit

I have monit working on several servers but when I install it on Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit server I get the following error reported in the log file and monitoring doesn't work.

```
[EDT Jun 24 21:26:20] error    : State file '/var/lib/monit/state': Unable to read magic
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I installed monit with apt-get install monit and the version is 5.3.2

Comment: does the file exist?  If it does, delete it, if doesn't -- verify that parent directory exists and is writable by monit.